# YouTube link not opening App (iOS/Chrome)

Tags: ios, google-chrome, youtube

I have created a basic web page that links to a few YouTube accounts. Each account has a custom URL as allocated by Google via Google+:

```
http://www.youtube.com/c/*channelName
```

The links work fine in iOS Safari and offers to open the YouTube app, which is the behaviour that I want, but when I click the links in iOS Chrome it simply sends me to the mobile YouTube website.

Anyone know why Chrome doesn't launch the YouTube app? Normally if you click a YouTube link in Chrome it does it by default, but I can't get it to work with this particular URL format.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Open settings in iOS Chrome
2. Google Apps
3. Turn on YouTube

YouTube was off by default on my iPhone.